Trouble finding description of the sound an oar makes in a crew boat
Hi Im having trouble describing the sound the oars make in this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Xn55OXxqJ8) when ignoring the rattling of the boat. I am thinking something like a "pft, put" sound but i want it to read almost like it sounds ideally. Anyway if you can help out that would be much appreciated.

I'll not present you with a solution that tells you which sound words you should use, because you might have found another solution that fits your style of writing better. Instead I'll explain how I would go about finding a solution to enable you to write better yourself.

First, I'd try to think of sound words that I know that are related to fluids, such as slosh, splash etc.

Then I would look in several dictionaries and thesauruses and see if I could find synonyms or related words. I might also search the internet for things like "other words for splash" or "sound words water" or "list of English onomatopoeia" and other similar searches.

In that way I would collect several words that seem more or less fitting to me. If there are good words among these that I want to use, my research is finished.

If there isn't, I'll try to vary the words I found or invent my own sound words. I'll use the phonetic properties of the language for that, knowing that speakers usually associate sibilants (/s, z, ʃ, ʒ/) and stridents (/f, v/) with fluids or air. Depending on whether the sound is high or low I would use lighter (/i/) or darker (/u, o/) vowels. If necessary, I would vary the length of the sound by repeating vowels ("oo" /u:/) or consonants ("ff", "sss").



Try this video for a better quality in the first minute or so.
The "put" is the sound when the oars enter the water. The "pft" is the sound when the oars are pulled back.
Could also be "splosh", "swoosh" I would suggest.
